# Regex for removing blocks of 3 or fewer characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to design a regex pattern that removes words less than 4 characters long. The catch is, any special characters (primarily: !@#$%^&*().,;? ) attached to the word e.g. "age?" will not meet the condition for removal, so "hi!!", "you?", "hello boy!" should all be retained from the input string. To illustrate:

```
string1='my name is jen!'
```

I tried the regex,

```
regex1=re.compile(r'\b.{,3}\s')
```

and coupled it with re.sub:

```
string2=re.sub(regex1,' ',string1)
```

and this works great except, 1. I have to sub the pattern with a space, and this sometimes has to be removed manually, and 2. It doesn't work if the 3 character or fewer 'word' is at the end of string.

```
string1='my name is jen'
re.sub(regex1,' ',string1)
out: ' name jen'
```

Is there a better regex that can be used? Should I instead try to retain 'words' that are 4 characters or more?

Comment: Did you try `string2=re.sub(regex1,'',string1)` ?

Comment: @Mika72 sure looks like the OP did.

Comment: Can the "words" you want include any word character? (`A-Za-z0-9_`) (and nothing but word characters?)

Comment: Yes they can, alphanumerics are fine.

Comment: Try `r'\s*(?<!\S)\S{1,3}(?!\S)\s*'` (for any non-whitespace chunks) or `r'\s*\b\w{1,3}(?!\S)\s*'` or `r'\s*\b\w{1,3}\b\s*'` (for word chars only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b\w{1,3}(?=\s|$)\s*
```

in your python code:

```
$ cat words3.py 
import re

string1='my name is jen!'
print(re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}(?=\s|$)\s*','',string1))
```

**output:**

```
name jen!
```

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/ZEzYtM/3/

**Note:** I have taken only into account that the punctuations and special characters will be attached at the end of the word.

If you want to avoid the removal of words like `!ab` then use:

```
(?<=\s)\b\w{1,3}(?=\s|$)\s*
```

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/ZEzYtM/4